# Return class that matches element from list

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a nodelist of elements in js that were collected by querying many classes and then a "for" statement that loops through the list. What I need is a quicky one-line way to return what class each element was selected by within the loop so I can perform an action based on that. Here is my code blip:

```
var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".class1, .class2, .etc...");
for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
    var classOfCurrentDiv = [...]
    //perform action using classOfCurrentDiv
}
```

I know I can do something like

```
if (nodeList[i].classList.contains(class1)) {
    //perform code
}
```

and repeat that for each class, or do a comparison of the element's classlist and the list of classes I'm searching for, but all I need to do is insert the name of the class into a string, so I'd prefer a single line solution to obtain the class that returned the element in the query. The class that returned the element may not be that element's only class which is why I can't just pull the element's classlist.

This is probably very simple and I'm just blanking on how to do it, but let me know. The list of queried classes will be hardcoded and each element's classlist will only contain one of the queried classes if that helps.

Thanks!

Comment: what if an element has both `class1` and `class2` which one do you use

Comment: By design, they should only have one, but if something goes wrong, it should prefer the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Element.matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) to do this with a 1 liner.

`Element.matches(selector)` lets you specify a css selector to an element and it will return if the element is matched by the selector. Since your selector works out to be a comma separated list of classes, you can find which class matched the particular element by splitting the selector on commas to an array, loop thru that array as each class via `filter` and filter out elements that don't match. Full example below:

```js
function classOfCurrentDiv(div, selector) {
    return selector.split(", ").filter(_class => div.matches(_class))[0];
}

const selector = ".class1, .class2, .class3";
const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
for (let i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
    console.log("selector of element " + i + ":", classOfCurrentDiv(nodeList[i], selector));
}
```

```html
<div class="class1 foo"></div>
<div class="class3 bar"></div>
<div class="class2 baz"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ?

```js
const classList = [".ps-fixed", ".class1", ".class2"]

const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(classList)

nodeList.forEach((node) => {
  classList.forEach((ClassMatch) => {
    if (node.classList.contains(ClassMatch.slice(1))) { //slice 1 to remove the "." before the class names in the array
      console.log(node)
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what I'm using right now, I was just wondering if there was a clever shorter version.

Comment: Nice, and for the shorter version you can't really if you want to check all classes and all nodes from the list you need at least 2 loops, btw can you accept the answer if this is what you are using :)